# Can't use soulutf8's underline inside \section when using hyperref

Tags: hyperref, section-titles, soulutf

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{soulutf8}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\section{\ul{Introduction}}

\end{document}
```

I'm trying to underline my section headers using `soul` (`soulutf8` to be precise). But when I also import `hyperref`, I get over 100 errors:

- `Use of \SOUL@n doesn't match its definition.`
- `Use of \HyPsd@RemoveMask doesn't match its definition.`
- `Undefined control sequence. \HyPsd@ProtectSpaces ...d@RemoveMask #1\HyPsd@End`
- `Use of \HyPsd@RemoveMask doesn't match its definition.\Hy@temp@A #1#2->\define@key`
- `Argument of \Hy@temp@A has an extra }.`
- `Paragraph ended before \Hy@temp@A was complete.`

The list goes on. It works if I try to underline regular text, but not with section headers. It also works if I don't import `hyperref`.

What is the problem here and how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The section text is also used in the bookmarks, and for this it is expanded, and complicated commands like \ul can error. You can use \textorpdfstring to provide a specific bookmark text.

inputenc and unicode is not needed with a current LaTeX. Both is now the default anyway.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soulutf8}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\section{\texorpdfstring{\ul{Introduction}}{Introduction}}

\end{document}
```

If you are using \ul a lot, you can also disable it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soulutf8}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\def\ul#1{#1}}

\begin{document}
\section{\ul{Introduction}}

\end{document}
```